# HTTP Response string from PHP to Android

Tags: java, php, android, string, http

I am verifying a user (email address and password) in database and and echo the result.

```
if($num_rows == 1)
{
    $usertypeid = mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
    echo $usertypeid[0];
}
else
{
    echo "invalid_user";
}
```

When i test it on a normal browser it prints exactly what i want. When I do http request from android, it returns the string correct. But it has something garbage value at first byte I guess which is not visible though.

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
strResult = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Then I am comparing strResult with a final string and check if it is not a failure.

```
if (!strResult.equals(Konstant.HTTP_RESULT_SIGNIN_FAILURE))
```

So, when strResult is actually "invalid_user" the condition should not pass. But it passes.

[image: String value of HTTP Response]

[image: Final String value]

If i use "endsWith()" instead of "equals()", it works fine. or If i use substring() to eliminate first byte and then use equals, it works fine.

Can anyone please help me what's happening here?

Comment: Have you tried to encode you PHP script file with UTF-8 without BOM?

Comment: @tato.rodrigo How do I do that?

Comment: What editor are you using? I use Notepad++ and it has a option to convert the file encoding under the "Format" menu. It worth give a try.

Comment: I use Notepadd++ too. And it is already UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I don't know What is BOM?

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom. On Notepad++, click the "Format" menu, then click the "Convert to UTF-8 (without BOM)". If this works, I will post an answer then you can accept it.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. BTW, I think they changed "Format" menu to "Encoding" menu.

Comment: In fact I use the Portuguese-BR translation of Notepad++ and the menu is called "Formatar", so I translated to english. But it seems that on the english version, it is called "Encoding". I answered this question, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the file as UTF-8 without BOM.

On Notepad++ you can do it by clicking the "Encoding" menu and then click the "Convert to UTF-8 (without BOM)" option.